# Removing unneccesary arrays in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run this code:

```
    $yearRes=DB::table('order')
            ->select(DB::raw("year(created_at) as y"))
            ->orderBy("created_at")
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(created_at)"))->get();
    foreach ($yearRes as $key => $value) {
        $totalOrder[]=DB::table('order')->select(DB::raw("year(created_at) as y,sum(item_price) as p,count(id) as i"))->whereYear('created_at', '=', $value->y)->get();
    }
```

It shows me this:

```
[[{"y":2016,"p":15050,"i":11}],[{"y":2017,"p":8440,"i":3}]]
```

When I run this code

```
 $abc=json_encode($totalOrder);
  $a=rtrim($abc);
  $title=explode('[', $a);
  $c=implode('', $title);
  $ac=rtrim($c,']');
```

...the result is this:

```
{"y":2016,"p":15050,"i":11}],{"y":2017,"p":8440,"i":3}
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
{"y":2016,"p":15050,"i":11},{"y":2017,"p":8440,"i":3}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: problem is not clear, what is your expected output ?

Comment: Why do you think these are "unnecessary arrays"? How do you intend to use the data afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
echo trim(json_encode(array_column($totalOrder, 0)), '[]');
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is what you want to do with the output and/or where and how wish to access the output; what it looks like is less irrelevant

Answer (score -1):

You don't need all those `rtrim`. What you're doing is a hack and not a real solution.

What you need to do is to append `->first()` on the code inside the foreach, in such :

```
$yearRes=DB::table('order')
            ->select(DB::raw("year(created_at) as y"))
            ->orderBy("created_at")
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(created_at)"))->get();
    foreach ($yearRes as $key => $value) {
        $totalOrder[]=DB::table('order')->select(DB::raw("year(created_at) as y,sum(item_price) as p,count(id) as i"))->whereYear('created_at', '=', $value->y)->get()->first();
    }
```

Then you can remove the `rtrims` and other unnecessary lines. Just keep the first line

```
$abc=json_encode($totalOrder);
```